# o365 email account: Programatically accessing To Alias in Internet Headers

Tags: email, outlook, office365, pop3

There is a problem accessing the To alias from a o365 account IF the from account is also o365.  If the from account is say, gmail, it works.

If I send an email to alias@mycompany.com which is an alias to realAccount@mycompany.com, if I examine the To header in Outlook, it will always show me the original alias.  If I view the header progrmatically, it will NOT show the alias if it was sent from an o365 account.  Instead, it shows the real account.  If I do this same test with a gmail instead of an o365 email it works -- shows the alias in the To: header as expected.

How does Outlook access this data?  The number of headers are different too.  Outlook contains more data.  Has anyone experienced this?  Any ideas on how to access the alias like Outlook does?

Header when accessing from Outlook:

```
From: o365Account@somecompany.com
To: ***************** alias@mycompany.com ****************
Subject: shdaKJSDHA
Thread-Topic: shdaKJSDHA
Thread-Index: AQHUSTkz1fQhzI5SG0ie26mNIvHmmQ==
Date: Mon, 10 Sep 2018 19:05:12 +0000
Message-ID: <---@-----.prod.outlook.com>
```

Header when accessed programatically:

```
From: o365Account@company.com
To: *****************realAccount@mycompany.com ****************
Subject: shdaKJSDHA
Thread-Topic: shdaKJSDHA
Thread-Index: AQHUSTkz1fQhzI5SG0ie26mNIvHmmQ==
X-MS-Exchange-MessageSentRepresentingType: 1
Date: Mon, 10 Sep 2018 19:05:12 +0000
Message-ID: <----@-----.prod.outlook.com>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Exchange always resolves the sender and recipients to their primary addresses both when sending and when receiving the messages. This is just the way it works.

Are you sending through SMTP?

Comment: When I send my test messages I am doing so from the UI at office365@outlook.com.  I am concerned with receiving the messages though.  I need to know which alias they were sent to in order to route logic accordingly.  For example, if it was sent to sales@ it should forward to a salesperson.  If it was sent to support@ it should make a case management ticket, etc.

Comment: If you are sending through Exchange to a user in the same domain, the alias gets resolved to an EX (as opposed to SMTP) when the message is submitted. Even if you use some other mail client (or send from a different domain), the recipient gets resolved to the EX address and Exchange server overwrites the MIME headers. I consider that a bug, but that's how Exchange always worked.

Comment: How does Outlook gain access to the alias though?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. The list of aliases is stored in the PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES MAPI property accessing using AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty in OOM.

Answer (score 0):

You know what I ended up doing?  I made a Distro list with 1 recipient.  The distro list takes the place of the alias.  It always shows the To: as the distro list.  That way it doesn't get lost.  Thank you for helping me understand Exchange Server dmitry-streblechenko.